# IN operator in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I was trying to filter the crystal report by using the IN operator like what we do in SQL. In crystal report, i was trying to do it the same way as something like this
**({i_NonPfcIncDetStt.TeamCode} IN ('ABC','DEF'))** but it's giving me error, **"The ) is mising"**.

Any idea how can i do this in crystal report?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
({i_NonPfcIncDetStt.TeamCode} IN ['ABC','DEF']) perhaps?
```

Answer (score 4):

Yep,  use the brackets not parens.

For fancy, you can put the to-match strings in a delimited string variable, and then use SPLIT.

```
@toMatchList
"ABC,DEF,MDV,HLV,ILY,TLA,OMG,LOL,GOD,ETC"
```

---

```
({i_NonPfcIncDetStt.TeamCode} in Split(@toMatchList, ","))
```

For extra-fancy, you can do pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
Month({Person.Date}) IN [7,8]
```